# Change color of activated page in Flexdashboard

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a problem with a flexdashboard. I want to change the color of the navigation bar for a dashboard with multiple pages to grey (in which I succeeded) and the color of an active / selected page or a page I hover over to yellow (which I cannot do). Here is the code I used. I am not sure how I can find the names of the navbar elements that I can change, so that I can change the navbar.

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---
<style>                     
.navbar {
  background-color:grey;
  hover-color:yellow;
}

</style>
```

The background comes out grey (like I want it to be), but the selected page or page I hover over stays blue. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

It will be tricky because you have to override all of the css elements controlling the hover colour. An easy workaround is to change the theme:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: <enter theme name>
---
```

The themes can be found on the [flexdashboard site](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#themes).

I also needed to do something similar, and I think I found most of the elements that need changing:

```
<style>
.navbar {
  background-color:grey;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

You can find the navbar elements you will need to change here: https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/v3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.css#L4643-L4744